# How to use same page anchor tags to hide/show content in Next.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

### **The problem**

The current project is using Next.js and this situation occurred: the content needs to be hidden or replaced, matching the current category selected. I want to do it without reloading or using another route to do so. And when the user presses F5 or reloads the page the content remains unchanged.

### **The attempts**

Next.js' [showcase](https://nextjs.org/showcase) page  apparently is able to do so. In the docs, there's a feature called ['Shallow routing'](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing), which basically gives the possibility to update the URL without realoading the page. That's what i figured out for now. Any clues on how the content is changed to match the category?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the content on the client based on the category passed in the URL fragment (`#` value) using `window.location.hash`.

Here's a minimal example of how to achieve this.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const data = {
    '#news': 'News Data',
    '#marketing': 'Marketing Data',
    default: "Default Data"
}

const ShowCasePage = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const [categoryData, setCategoryData] = useState()

    const changeCategory = (category) => {
        // Trigger fragment change to fetch the new data
        router.push(`/#${category}`, undefined, { shallow: true });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const someData = data[window.location.hash] ?? data.default // Retrieve data based on URL fragment
        setCategoryData(someData);
    }, [router])

    return (
        <>
            <div>Showcase Page</div>
            <button onClick={() => changeCategory('news')}>News</button>
            <button onClick={() => changeCategory('marketing')}>Marketing</button>
            <div>{categoryData}</div>
        </>
    )
}

export default ShowCasePage
```